# How can I center a wrapper <div> so that it isn't positioned underneath a fixed vertical navigation bar?

Tags: css, wrapper

I currently have this for my navigation bar:

```
#nav-bar {
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

I want to have it so any elements that are positioned to the right of it don't go underneath the nav bar and I want to be able to center a wrapper `<div>` so that it is centered according to the rest of the page that *isn't* taken up by the navigation bar.

I have tried implementing a wrapper `<div>` that was positioned underneath the vertical navigation bar but I failed considerably.

This is currently what I have so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXkKKo

Comment: Please add HTML as well. you can use codepen to demonstrate your problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very clear about what you want, but try this,

**HTML :**

```
<div id="nav-bar"></div>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content center">
   Test Content
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#nav-bar {
position:fixed;
float:left;
width:300px;
height:100%;
background-color:#000000;
}
.wrapper{
  background-color:#ff0000;
  margin-left:300px;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}
.center{
  background-color:#0000ff;
  width:300px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRmWPA

Comment: This is currently what I have:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXkKKo

I am wanting to have the navigation bar on the right, have an image banner at the top and have content that is centered below the image banner.

I'm so sorry for the confusion, this is my first post and I appreciate the help you have given so far